# How to pass the bash equivalent "$@" from expect script

Tags: bash, command-line, tcl, expect, argv

I have an expect script which is a wrapper around a bash script which is a wrapper around scp.  :)

Basically, I would call my bash script like so.

```
myscp host /path filenames
```

This would ask me for root password on host.  And, I am tired of having to type in root all the time.  host is a test machine with a ramdisk so I can't setup ssh on host.    So I've played around with expect and I think it will do the job.

Anyways, I can pick out positional arguments in my expect script like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set host [lindex $argv 0];
set path [lindex $argv 1];
#but how to get filenames??
[...]
spawn myscp $host $path $filenames
```

So far, I've tried set filenames [lrange $argv 2 end], but that just results in a single argument containing all the filenames with space separators.

Anyways, I basically want to pass "$@" to myscp.  Or even less ambitious, $@ assuming no spaces in filename.

How would I do so in expect?

thanks.

Comment: BTW, I'd actually suggest tagging this as a tcl question rather than a bash question, as expect uses tcl syntax here; knowing bash well doesn't equip one to answer it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
set host [lindex $argv 0]
set path [lindex $argv 1]
set filenames [lrange $argv 2 end]

# or, the less readable
set filenames [lassign $argv host path]

# and then
spawn myscp $host $path {*}$filenames
```

the `{*}` syntax splits a list into its individual elements. If your Expect is too old to understand that, you'll have to resort to @Dinesh's `eval` answer.

Expect is an extension of the Tcl language, and the `{*}` syntax is documented as rule #5 of http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm

Comment: Thanks!  That worked.  I'd bang my head for hours and not come up with this solution.  Hehehe... you saved me alot of headaches.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there buddy. You just need to add `eval` before the `spawn`. That would be sufficient.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

eval spawn myscp [lrange $argv 0 end]
```

The `lrange` will extract the command line arguments from 0th index to last index which will be the equivalent of `$@` from bash scripts.

Reference : [eval](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/eval.htm) & [Exploring Expect](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565920903.do)

Comment: Yeah, I tried that too, but that didn't work.  But thanks for the suggestion.  I get 'eval no such file or directory'.  Then I tried putting bash -x in front that appears to go further, but now I get all these debug stuff, which isn't desirable, and seems to mess up expect.